# Unity. Определить, находится ли в зоне видимости объект. Закрасить зону видимости

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно определить, находится ли игрок в зоне видимости детектора и визуализировать зону видимости (Очень похожая ситуация на скриншоте). Не могу понять с помощью чего. Думал с помощью Raycast / Boxcast, но не смог найти способ ограничить boxcast при попадании в объект, чтобы за ним детектор ничего не проверял.
[image: Закрашена зона видимости]

Comment: Вопрос не то что бы 1-в-1 но совпадает процентов на 80

Comment: Спасибо большое, правда очень похоже!